# vectorized ifelse Rstudio

Tags: r, if-statement, rstudio

Writing a vectorized `ifelse()` I am trying to create and assign a new variable back to the data frame.

```
set.seed(1)
heights <- data.frame(
height_ft = sample(  seq(from=5.5, to=6.1, length=10)  , 50, replace=T), 
gender    = sample(c("M","F"),50, replace=T)  )
```

Here are my attempts:

```
y = ifelse(gender = "F", 1,0)
##ERROR

if (gender = "F" & under_rep = 1){ print ("1") } 
else if (gender = "F" & under_rep = 0) { print ("0") }
##ERROR
```

Comment: Replace `=` with `==` in the `if` and `ifelse` statements.  `==` is what you use for logical checking of exact equality

Comment: I agree it should be closed. I'm wondering if that could be any new question about `if(){}else{}` and `ifelse` that could be asked. There are almost 4,000 [r] ifelse questions. This one is of low quality because it fails to include the actual error message.

Comment: If you ever use `else if` you should probably also be using an `else` for the last one

Answer (score 1):

As @BondedDust pointed out, the error message was not included in the post, which would have been helpful. But its not hard to reproduce this error from the code.

The error is `Error in ifelse(gender = "F", 1, 0) : unused argument (gender = "F")`.

The "unused argument" in the error message comes from R not finding `gender` anywhere in its environment, because the `heights` dataframe where it resides is not called, as in `heights$gender`.

But as @Richard_Scriven points out, the conditional is not used correctly either. Should be a `==` instead of `=`.

Lastly, assigning new var back into the dataframe is not address with the use of `y` instead of `heights$y`.

Comment: Your statement *The "unused argument" in the error message comes from R not finding gender anywhere in its environment...* is not right.  R is looking for the argument `gender` in `ifelse` and since `ifelse` does not have a `gender` argument, the error is triggered.  It's not looking outside the function argument list.